# Pass an argument by reference in C++/CLI so re-assignment affects the caller

Tags: c++-cli, pass-by-reference

Probably this is not a difficult question, but I am always a little bit confused on how to treat String type as an argument in Visual C++. I have the following to functions:

```
void function_1(String ^str_1)
{
  str_1 = gcnew String("Test");
}

void function_2()
{
  String ^str_2 = nullptr;
  function_1(str_2);
}
```

After calling `function_1`, `str_2` is still equal to `null`, but what I want to achieve is that `str_2` is equal to `Test`. So, how can I achieve that the content of `str_1` is passed to `function_2`?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use a [tracking reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a(VS.80).aspx):

```
void function_1(String ^%str_1)
{
  str_1 = gcnew String("Test");
}
```

**Explanation:** Passing `String ^` is like passing a pointer. Changes are only made to the local copy of the reference. `String ^%` is like passing a reference to a reference... just as you would pass a pointer to a pointer when calling a function that should change the original pointer.

Comment: Thanks! Learnt something today!

Comment: @Agnel I don't get why you said that when you pass a pointer only local copies of the reference are changed. First of all a pointer is not a reference. Secondly, if you pass a pointer in c++ and modify the data it points to, you are not modifying a local copy of the data. Did I get mixed up in the semantics or what?

Comment: @Ian, What I meant was that if you pass a pointer and change the value of the pointer variable itself (as opposed to the value of the data it points to), only the value of the local pointer variable will change. And yes, if you modify the data a pointer points to, the data itself is modified and not the local copy. No local copy of the data exists; a local copy of the pointer does exist.