# change variable value by reference c++/windows forms

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I'm trying to change a variable value by reference (with a function).

My Function:

```
void chgVariable(String^ *trgvari,String^ trgvarival)
{
 *trgvari = trgvarival;
}
```

My Variable:

```
String^ myStringVar;
```

How do I use:

```
chgVariable(&myStringVar, gcnew String("Test"));
```

but i get this error:

Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::interior_ptr' to 'String ^*'

Comment: Have you tried making the `trgvari` argument a proper C++ reference instead of a pointer to a C++CLI "pointer"? E.g. declare it as `String^& trgvari` and then pass it without the address-of operator when calling the function.

Comment: same error.
I'm "creating" the variable in 'private region'

private:
System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

String^ myStringVar;
Have a problem?

Comment: You'll need to use a managed reference: void chgVariable(String^% trgvari, String^ trgvarival)

Answer (score 0):

You have the definition of the first argument wrong. It should be:

```
void chgVariable(String* ^trgvari,String^ trgvarival)
```

If you start with `String^ myStringVar`, then `&myStringVar` becomes a pointer to a `String^`, which is shown as `String*^`.

Also, now when you dereference it, you should get `String^`, like you want.

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately, C++CLI doesn't allow pointers to handles, so you should make it a reference to a handle like so:

```
void chgVariable(String^% trgvari,String^ trgvarival)
```

and change `&myStringVar` to just `myStringVar`.

Lots of credit to this other stackoverflow question: [Pass an argument by reference in C++/CLI so re-assignment affects the caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059992/pass-an-argument-by-reference-in-c-cli-so-re-assignment-affects-the-caller)

Comment: now i get this error: 'an ordinary pointer to a C++/CLI ref class or interface class is not allowed'

Comment: Gah, this is why I don't like C++CLI :). Try instead making it `String^^ trgvari`, and `%myStringVar`

Comment: this works when I create variable inside of a function,but when I create outside of a function,doesn't works

Comment: Alright, I looked around a little more, and I have updated my answer.

Comment: when I use 'String^ ^trgvari' i get this error: 'handle to handle,pointer,or reference is not allowed'

Comment: I switched it, it should now be `String^% trgvari`. Also, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059992/pass-an-argument-by-reference-in-c-cli-so-re-assignment-affects-the-caller