# C++/CLI passing a String ^ as a tracking reference doesn't work as expected

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am using C++/CLI with VS 2010. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3060012/3092979) answer I have learned that in C++/CLI you pass an object by reference like so

```
voin func(String ^ %string){
//modify string
}
```

What I want to do, is pass some arguments to a constructor of a `GetInput` form. Then modify them from the user input to this form. When the form closes, the caller form will get values entered in the `GetInput` form.

And it worked for me with a `List<double>`, but not with a `String^`. Here is the code:

```
public ref class GetInput : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    List<double>^ _data;
    String ^ _string_data;

    GetInput(List<double>^ %data, String ^ %string_data){
        _data = data;
        _string_data = string_data;
        //this code is here just for the sake of an example, 
        //it's actually in one of the methods
        _data->Add(0.5); 
        _string_data = "15";
    }
    //void buttonClickHandler where i actually want to modify data and string_data
}
```

The `List _data` gets modified, as well as the passed `data`, but when I modify the `String _string_data`, original `string_data` is left untouched. However if I modify the `string_data` itself - it works fine. Also, tracking reference can't be a member of the class, so declaring _string_data as a reference doesn't work.

The obvious workaround would be to pass the `List^` consisting of one `String^`, but I would like to know why doesn't it work and if there is a way to make my approach work. Coming from native C++, this seemed like a pretty straightforward approach - just pass the pointer to the data. But C++/ClI tracking references are something different.

Also I read that "A tracking reference is updated when the object moves on the garbage-collected heap." ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a(v=vs.100).aspx)). Can somebody clarify what this means? I suspect this contains an answer to my question, but I can't quite understand it:)

**UPDATE:**
Basically I want to do this in C++/CLI:

```
class GetInput {
    string * s; 
    GetInput(string * caller_wants_this_modified){ 
        s = caller_wants_this_modified; 
    } 
    void method_to_modify_the_string(){ 
        (*s) = "New string value"; // modifies the string passed by the caller 
    } 
}
```

I need to save the pointer passed to constructor as a class member and then change the data, this pointer points to, in one of the member functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But C++/ClI tracking references are something different

Thinking that there is something magical about a "tracking reference" is perhaps what is getting you into trouble here.  The C++/CLI language and documentation plays this up the heavy, it was written for native C++ programmers.  It is *actually* not that different it all.

It is just a pointer.

It behaves exactly like a pointer as well, both physically on the processor and syntactically.  The only thing that "special" about it is that the garbage collector can find it back.  Necessary so it can do its job.  The C++/CLI designers chose to use `^` instead of `*` because they do have restrictions.  Plain ones, you for example can't make it a member of an unmanaged class.  The GC has no way to know where it is located in memory so can't do its job.

Your problem is a very simple one, you have **two** pointers.  `_string_data` and `string_data`.  Do note that your choice of names does not exactly help you to get it right.  You updated the _string_data pointer, after the assignment it now points to "15".  But **not** the pointer you passed by reference, it still points to the original string.  So of course no changes are propagated back to the caller.  No idea what was intended, but arbitrarily:

```
  _string_data = "15";
  string_data = _string_data;
```

And now the caller will also see its reference updated to "15".  Both pointers now point to the same object.

Do note that you got it wrong for the `List<>` argument as well.  You did **not** update the `data` pointer.  Nor did you need to, you didn't create a new List object.  Your code only modified the object, not the pointer to the object.  So passing it by reference was entirely unnecessary.

---

One more detail is relevant to this question.  Note that you modified the List<> object by calling its Add() method.  But you cannot do the same thing for the String.  It is *immutable*, none of its methods and properties allows you to modify its content.  That gives it very desirable behavior, a string is always thread-safe and always safe to pass as an argument to a method.  Secure that it can never be modified.  It behaves like a value.

Or in other words, you *have* to pass the string pointer by reference to propagate changes back to the caller.

Beware that List<> is not immutable, your Add() call mutated the heck out of the object.  The client programmer that uses your class is unlikely to expect that to happen.  The *const* keyword in C++ is a pretty good way to express the difference.  It however doesn't work at that well in C++/CLI, other .NET languages don't know beans about it.  You can use *const* in a declaration, it can't be enforced at runtime.

Comment: I see my mistake now. But I still don't get how to accomplish my goal. I updated the question to make my goal clear.

Comment: Hmya, you are asking for a dangling pointer bug.  Generally a very bad idea in C++ as well, disaster strikes when the object that stores the pointer is deleted and your class keeps using it.  You can't create dangling pointer bugs in managed code.  You must create a ref class that stores the string reference, your function needs to return a reference to an object of that class.  Now both the caller and your own code can use that object to retrieve the same string.  Exact same way it is solved in C++, you use the std::shared_ptr class.