# How to pass an int from C# to C++ by reference?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Is it possible to pass a int from C# to C++ by reference?

I have a simple method in C++ that just increment a number and print messages.

```
void ProcessOrder(int& num)
{
    int start = num;
    int stop = num + 10;

    for (int i = start; i < stop; i++)
    {
        cout << "[Legacy] counting " << i << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    // Note the above was original posted code and I made a stupid mistake and was never
    // even changing `num` value passed by reference. The correct function to test
    // should be as below (discard all of the above)
    num =  num + 5; // just modify the number to any value
}
```

Now I want to call this from C++/CLI and then that from C#.

```
void StoreWrapper::ProcessOrder(int^ num)
{
    LegacyStore* legacyStore = new LegacyStore();
    legacyStore->ProcessOrder(num); // error here
}
```

But this returns compiler error:

```
error C2664: 'void LegacyStore::ProcessOrder(int &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'System::Int32 ^' to 'int &'
```

I made sure all three projects are x86 but the error still persists. To be price, the CLR module is Win32 and C# Console application is x86.

The issues are here:

If I declare `void StoreWrapper::ProcessOrder(int& num)` then this method compiles but now I believe its pure C++? I can't call this from C# side, get the following compiler err:

```
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'int*'
```

If I declare it `void StoreWrapper::ProcessOrder(int^ num)' now the method doesn't even compile.

I have tried using `System::Int32` variable type but same result.

Is there a way I pass int to C++ from .NET world by reference? Is it possible if C++ side is 32 bit and .NET side is 64 bit?

**Update**

The C# code is here, basically I want the number to get updated in the code below.

```
  int number = 0;
  Console.WriteLine("Original number = {0}", number);
  store.ProcessOrder(ref number);
  Console.WriteLine("After ProcessOrder number = {0}", number);
```

The answer by dxiv unfortunately doesn't update the number above.

Comment: You need to use `int%`.  Very similar to int&, but the garbage collector can track it.  int^ forces the int to be boxed, a feature not available in C# (looks like System.ValueType in the metadata).

Comment: @HansPassant It's definitely not duplicate of the tagged question. This question is between .NET and C++ boundary, not just passing by reference within C++/CLI environment which is simply done with % sign.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059992/pass-an-argument-by-reference-in-c-cli-so-re-assignment-affects-the-caller/3060012#3060012

Comment: @zar The last line under "*Update*" says it still "*doesn't update*". Is that still the case?

Comment: @dxiv I had literally copy/pasted your code but I am going to rerun it what I could have missing. Will update tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting to use `num` directly like `ProcessOrder(num);` fails with the error quoted in the original post "*cannot convert argument 1 from `System::Int32 ^` to `int &`*" because of the different levels of indirection between the passed (pointer) variable and the expected (reference) argument.

Attempting to fix that with `ProcessOrder(*num);` corrects the indirection and gets the types to match, but fails to compile with the error "*an object from the gc heap (an unboxed value type) cannot be converted to a native reference*". This points to the real issue, which is that an unmanaged/unboxed reference cannot point into the gc managed heap, which is subject to compacting and reshuffles.

The easiest solution is to use a [tracking reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/tracking-reference-operator-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2019) `int%` instead, as advised in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3060012/5538420) to the question linked as a duplicate.

```
void StoreWrapper::ProcessOrder(int% num)
{
    LegacyStore* legacyStore = new LegacyStore();

    legacyStore->ProcessOrder(*&num);  // shorthand for:
                                       //
                                       // int &n = *&num;
                                       // legacyStore->ProcessOrder(n);
                                       // num = n;
}

// to be called from C# as:
//
// int number = 0;
// store.ProcessOrder(ref number);
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]   It is also possible to use `num` by address, though that requires explicit pinning.

```
void StoreWrapper::ProcessOrder([System::Runtime::InteropServices::Out] int %num)
{
    LegacyStore* legacyStore = new LegacyStore();

    pin_ptr<int> p = &num;
    legacyStore->ProcessOrder(*p);
}

// to be called from C# as:
//
// int number = 0;
// store.ProcessOrder(out number);
```

---

[ *EDIT #2* ]   Edited code and added comments to cover returning the value to the C# caller.

Comment: I am looking for 2nd way only so the calling variable value is updated but the code above doesn't build. I builds if I do `pin_ptr<int> p = &num;` but that doesn't update the calling variable.

Comment: @zar 1) If you want the first wrapper to return the value to the caller you need to change the argument to `int^ %num`. This is explained in the question linked as a duplicate.

Comment: @zar 2) For the second wrapper, what version of the compiler are you using? The above compiles and works fine with my VS 2019 v16.5.4. The change you propose `pin_ptr<int> p = &num;` does *not* compile, with "*error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'System::Int32 ^\*' to 'cli::pin_ptr<int>'*".

Comment: @zar In fact, attempting `pin_ptr<int> p = num;` directly fails to compile with the same "*C2440*", and also gives the additional message "*Cannot implicitly unbox, apply `&*` to the rvalue*".

Comment: It does build if I don't call it but results in error when I call it om C# code, Please see my update to question with code.

Comment: I am using VS 2019 v16.6.2

Comment: @zar Please see the new edit, hope it addresses that part of the question.

Comment: Thanks, now it builds but caller value still doesn't get updated. I am thinking this maybe impossible to pass by reference from .NET world to native world.

Comment: @zar The caller value *does* get updated in both cases. I rechecked with new projects  started from scratch just to be sure. Sorry, not sure what you are doing differently.

Comment: I copy pasted your code just to be sure, are you calling this from a C# console application? Because this project is obviously in C++/CLI project.

Comment: @zar Yes, the calls quoted in the code comments are made from a C# console app which references the C++/CLI assembly.

Comment: Sorry for late follow up. Just tried again and it is working! The reason I didn't see it change before was because if you notice, my legacy Process() was not really changing the reference value so obviously it was never getting changed. I fixed that and it does change. Good one! Thanks!

Comment: @zar When it catches my eye I'll give them the satisfaction that it didn't pass unnoticed ;-)